# Python control Basemap size figure in combined plot

Tags: matplotlib-basemap, subplot

How to control basemap size in combined plot in this image?. At moment I used this command line fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10)) for both image at plt.subplot(211) and plt.subplot(212) however the map size does not move accordingly at same size with histogram. The output is as follows:

[image: Basemap in Combined Plot]

Comment: Can you post your code as well to be able to reproduce this issue?